# How to create a "content only" project in a Visual Studio 2017 solution?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api2, visual-studio-2017, class-library

Is there an easier way to create content only projects in Visual Studio 2017 with out having to edit `csproj` files?

My objective is to have a class library project  in my solution that does not produce and assembly/dll.

Comment: What would be the result of building a "content only" project? There are shared projects which just include files in the referencing projects, which might be what you are after.

Comment: If you don't need to do anything with the files why just having them in "solution folder" (without any projects) is not enough? Also is there any particular reason why  you are trying to make csproj to not be C# project (like not build assembly as output)?

Comment: What is a "content only project" anyway? What content are you talking about? How would you expect to reference this content?

Answer (score 2):

`ASP.NET Empty Web Site` is the project type you are looking for.  It is located under `Visual C#`-`Web`-`Previous Versions`.

**Project file structure**

There is no project file (.csproj or .vbproj). All the files in a folder structure are automatically included in the site.

**Compilation**

If you do include source code in the project, the source code is typically compiled dynamically (automatically) by ASP.NET on the server the first time a request is received after the site has been installed or updated.

**Deployment**

You copy the application source files to a computer that has IIS installed on it, or use visual studio tools that integrate with Web Deploy (the IIS web deployment tool) to automate many deployment tasks.

**Limitations**

There are a number of limitations to these project types but if you are only looking for static content and no compiled assemblies, the limitations should not affect you.

There is much more documentation located [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547590(v=vs.110).aspx) regarding the specifics of this project type.